# Getting response code 403 on API data in requests python

Tags: python, get, request, http-status-code-403

The following python script gives me 403 error, the type of request is 'GET'.

```
import requests
import json
url ='https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players?pageSize=30&compSeasons=210&altIds=true&page=2&type=player&id=-1&compSeasonId=210'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(result.status_code)
```

A Screenshot:

[Check XHR Request Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlzo6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I ran it and got the same 403 response. But if you open the url you posted, you'll notice a 403 error there as well. This looks like an issue with the website itself or maybe you are using an incorrect url.

Comment: You can check the url here. Try https://www.premierleague.com/players. Then go to the network tab through inspect element & start scrolling the page.You will find the same url in xhr requests.

Comment: The URL seems correct. I don't think we are allowed to access it. At least that's what the error code 403 represents. 

"The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason."

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late answer, but what you're missing is the correct header to access the Pulselive API. The necessary header is `'Origin':'https://www.premierleague.com'`.
This makes the API think that the request is coming from the official Premier League website, and they have access to the API.
Hope this helps!